# Is there any way to open video in external app like Mx player or any others apps in flutter project?

Tags: flutter, dart, video, video-streaming, vlc

**In an application i am working on I need to be able to play videos through other apps like ,MX players, etc. How do i open these apps in flutter.**

Answer (score 1):

You can use a great package like [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file).

```dart
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';

OpenFile.open("/sdcard/example.txt");
//OpenFile.open("/sdcard/example.txt", type: "text/plain", uti: "public.plain-text");
```

Comment: You should probably get the file you are trying to modify, not from a link.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late but I'm sure I can help someone with the same problem.
You must install this plugin:
[android_intent_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus).

example:

```
AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
        action: 'action_view',
        type: "video/*",
        data: linkVideo,
      );
      intent.launch();
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://pub.dev/packages/external_app_launcher) package will help you to open external application from your phone.

You will just have to write below line of code where the package name will differ for every single app you want to open.

```
await LaunchApp.isAppInstalled(androidPackageName: 'net.pulsesecure.pulsesecure', iosUrlScheme: 'pulsesecure://');
```

Comment: He opened the app but I didn't know how to give him the link. Can you help me please

Comment: If you want to open a link, then you will have to use ```url_launcher``` package. But you can't open an specific media player with a video link.